# Question about $L$ = { $ww$ | $w$ ∊ $ca^*c$}

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I found a grammar for this language.

$S->caZac |cccc $.

$Z->aZa | cc$

But if I try to use pumping lemma for context-free languages on $L$ with the word: $ca^ncca^nc$ I obtain it's not context-free. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The pumping lemma is verified with a pumping length $n=6$. Indeed, let $ww\in L$, $|ww| \geqslant n$. Then $ww =ca^kcca^kc$ with $k\geqslant 1$.

Then $ww = uvxyz$ with $u = ca^{k-1}$, $v = a$, $x=cc$, $y=a$ and $z=a^{k-1}c$, and:

1. $|vxy| = 4 \leqslant n$;
2. $|vy| = 2 > 0$;
3. for $i\geqslant 0$, $uv^ixyv^iz = ca^{k-1+i}cca^{k-1+i}c\in L$.

Comment: But if I choose n = 1, $|vwy|$ = 4 > 1, with $v$ = $a$, $x$ = $cc$ and $y$ = $a$.

Comment: Then your choice of $n$ is wrong, but that is not a contradiction. The pumping lemma states that if $L$ is context-free, then **THERE EXISTS** such a $n$, not that the result is true for all $n$.